# Force PostgreSQL to use hashed join in query

Tags: postgresql, performance

I am doing some performance tuning and there is 1 particular query that comes up in the postgres log.

Query pasted below:

```
select distinct sc.CAPABILITY_NAME as "CAPABILITY" from SYSTEM_CAPABILITY sc join ROLE_CAPABILITY urc on urc.CAPABILITY=sc.CAPABILITY_NAME join ROLE_CAPABILITY grc on grc.CAPABILITY=urc.CAPABILITY join GROUP_USER gu on gu.ROLE=urc.ROLE_NAME join GROUP_ROLE gr on gr.ROLE_NAME=grc.ROLE_NAME where gu.USERNAME='TEST123' and (gu.EXPIRY_DATE is null or gu.EXPIRY_DATE>'2020-11-17 00:00:00+01') and gr.ID=gu.GROUP_ID and gu.GROUP_ID='ABC123'
```

When I run this query directly against the database it takes milliseconds however when it runs from the Java application it takes over 2 seconds.

I enabled the below in the postgres config file.
session_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'
auto_explain.log_min_duration = '1s'

On running the query from my local I can see that comparing against the run from the Java application that my local uses a hash join where as the run from the java application uses a nested loop.

I have then enabled the setting enable_hashjoin = on just as a test but it looks like the test via the Java application is still using the nested loop. I ran the query at the same time as the Java application but it takes only 17ms and uses the hash_join.

Firstly is it wise to make such changes to the postgres config file. I understand that this could also impact other queries its more of a test phase at the moment to assess the impact.

Secondly other than setting the enable_hashjoin = on is there anything else I need to do to prevent the nested loops being as first point of call for the queries.

Query results from the auto_explain are below:

Java App

```
< 2020-11-18 10:55:57.012 CET >LOG:  duration: 2212.992 ms  execute S_107:  select distinct sc.CAPABILITY_NAME as "CAPABILITY" from SYSTEM_CAPABILITY sc join ROLE_CAPABILITY urc on urc.CAPABILITY=sc.CAPABILITY_NAME join ROLE_CAPABILITY grc on grc.CAPABILITY=urc.CAPABILITY join GROUP_USER gu on gu.ROLE=urc.ROLE_NAME join GROUP_ROLE gr on gr.ROLE_NAME=grc.ROLE_NAME where gu.USERNAME=$1 and (gu.EXPIRY_DATE is null or gu.EXPIRY_DATE>$2) and gr.ID=gu.GROUP_ID and gu.GROUP_ID=$3
< 2020-11-18 10:55:57.012 CET >DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'TEST123', $2 = '2020-11-17 00:00:00+01', $3 = 'ABC123'
< 2020-11-18 10:55:57.014 CET >LOG:  duration: 2212.984 ms  plan:
    Query Text:  select distinct sc.CAPABILITY_NAME as "CAPABILITY" from SYSTEM_CAPABILITY sc join ROLE_CAPABILITY urc on urc.CAPABILITY=sc.CAPABILITY_NAME join ROLE_CAPABILITY grc on grc.CAPABILITY=urc.CAPABILITY join GROUP_USER gu on gu.ROLE=urc.ROLE_NAME join GROUP_ROLE gr on gr.ROLE_NAME=grc.ROLE_NAME where gu.USERNAME=$1 and (gu.EXPIRY_DATE is null or gu.EXPIRY_DATE>$2) and gr.ID=gu.GROUP_ID and gu.GROUP_ID=$3
    HashAggregate  (cost=78.40..78.44 rows=4 width=19)
      Group Key: sc.capability_name
      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.49..78.39 rows=4 width=19)
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.22..77.12 rows=4 width=38)
                  Join Filter: ((gu.role)::text = (urc.role_name)::text)
                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.93..62.56 rows=30 width=36)
                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..9.82 rows=1 width=85)
                              ->  Index Only Scan using idx_gp_usr_gp_usrnm_rl_exp_dt on group_user gu  (cost=0.42..8.46 rows=1 width=26)
                                    Index Cond: ((group_id = ($3)::text) AND (username = ($1)::text))
                                    Filter: ((expiry_date IS NULL) OR (expiry_date > $2))
                              ->  Seq Scan on group_role gr  (cost=0.00..1.35 rows=1 width=112)
                                    Filter: ((id)::text = ($3)::text)
                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on role_capability grc  (cost=4.51..52.44 rows=30 width=33)
                              Recheck Cond: ((role_name)::text = (gr.role_name)::text)
                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pk_role_capability  (cost=0.00..4.51 rows=30 width=0)
                                    Index Cond: ((role_name)::text = (gr.role_name)::text)
                  ->  Index Scan using idx_role_capability_capability on role_capability urc  (cost=0.28..0.42 rows=5 width=33)
                        Index Cond: ((capability)::text = (grc.capability)::text)
            ->  Index Only Scan using idx_system_capability_capability_name on system_capability sc  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=19)
                  Index Cond: (capability_name = (urc.capability)::text)
```

Run from my local machine connecting to DB

```
< 2020-11-18 10:58:50.297 CET >LOG:  duration: 16.070 ms  plan:
    Query Text: 
    select distinct sc.CAPABILITY_NAME as "CAPABILITY" from SYSTEM_CAPABILITY sc join ROLE_CAPABILITY urc on urc.CAPABILITY=sc.CAPABILITY_NAME join ROLE_CAPABILITY grc on grc.CAPABILITY=urc.CAPABILITY join GROUP_USER gu on gu.ROLE=urc.ROLE_NAME join GROUP_ROLE gr on gr.ROLE_NAME=grc.ROLE_NAME where gu.USERNAME='TEST123' and (gu.EXPIRY_DATE is null or gu.EXPIRY_DATE>'2020-11-17 00:00:00+01') and gr.ID=gu.GROUP_ID and gu.GROUP_ID='ABC123'
    
    HashAggregate  (cost=93.77..94.27 rows=50 width=19) (actual time=15.997..16.021 rows=200 loops=1)
      Group Key: sc.capability_name
      ->  Hash Join  (cost=16.86..93.65 rows=50 width=19) (actual time=0.325..15.295 rows=2329 loops=1)
            Hash Cond: ((urc.role_name)::text = (gu.role)::text)
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.07..78.20 rows=169 width=77) (actual time=0.139..14.106 rows=5861 loops=1)
                  Join Filter: ((sc.capability_name)::text = (urc.capability)::text)
                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.79..63.64 rows=30 width=82) (actual time=0.132..5.677 rows=1076 loops=1)
                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.51..54.09 rows=30 width=63) (actual time=0.124..0.447 rows=1076 loops=1)
                              ->  Seq Scan on group_role gr  (cost=0.00..1.35 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.015..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
                                    Filter: ((id)::text = 'ABC123'::text)
                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 27
                              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on role_capability grc  (cost=4.51..52.44 rows=30 width=33) (actual time=0.107..0.302 rows=1076 loops=1)
                                    Recheck Cond: ((role_name)::text = (gr.role_name)::text)
                                    Heap Blocks: exact=37
                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pk_role_capability  (cost=0.00..4.51 rows=30 width=0) (actual time=0.098..0.098 rows=1076 loops=1)
                                          Index Cond: ((role_name)::text = (gr.role_name)::text)
                        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_system_capability_capability_name on system_capability sc  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1076)
                              Index Cond: (capability_name = (grc.capability)::text)
                              Heap Fetches: 1076
                  ->  Index Scan using idx_role_capability_capability on role_capability urc  (cost=0.28..0.42 rows=5 width=33) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=5 loops=1076)
                        Index Cond: ((capability)::text = (grc.capability)::text)
            ->  Hash  (cost=11.62..11.62 rows=13 width=26) (actual time=0.179..0.179 rows=279 loops=1)
                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
                  ->  Index Only Scan using idx_gp_usr_gp_usrnm_rl_exp_dt on group_user gu  (cost=0.42..11.62 rows=13 width=26) (actual time=0.023..0.110 rows=279 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: ((group_id = 'ABC123'::text) AND (username = 'TEST123'::text))
                        Filter: ((expiry_date IS NULL) OR (expiry_date > '2020-11-16 23:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                        Heap Fetches: 4
```

I am using postgres version 9.5.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try to collect an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE), not just EXPLAIN, on each. Note that auto_explain.log_analyze can be very costly on older hardware or kernels, so you might not want to leave it set permanently.  But it is also very useful.

Comment: @jjanes I did not know that feature existed, will give it a try and see what I unearth. Thanks